# How are invalid regex escapes handled?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6

I've recently created an implementation of C++11 std::regex, which passes many conformance tests. Since the C++11 std::regex syntax and semantics are derived from ECMAScript 5.1, I thought I'd run those same tests against a browser, to check how closely the behaviour matches.

I discovered a couple of odd discrepancies in handling of invalid escape sequences.

```
/* As expected, matching the standard: */
/\,/.exec(",") -> [","]

/* Err... this should throw, it doesn't match any ECMAScript production:
   IdentityEscape := SourceCharacter but not IdentifierPart (ES 5.1)
                     SourceCharacter but not UnicodeIDContinue (ES 6.0) */
/\z/.exec("z") -> ["z"] (Chrome & Firefox!)

/* It even works for characters that have a defined meaning: */
/\u/.exec("u") -> ["u"] (Chrome)
                  null (Firefox)

/* Errr...! This is creepiest, it matches a backslash!!! */
/\c/.exec("\\c") -> ["\c"] (Chrome & Firefox!)
```

Are these known conformance issues in Chrome and Firefox, or are they conforming to some previous/future ECMAScript behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the specs titled [ECMAScript IdentityEscape is ambiguous](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2584). The discussion there indicates that browsers are using this rule to fix the issue:

> ```
> IdentityEscape ::
>  SourceCharacter but not c
> ```

Indeed, I can confirm [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749829(v=vs.85).aspx) lists the fix.

Keep in mind that the spec states:

> ```
> SourceCharacter ::
>  any Unicode code unit
> ```

So the line there means that `\,`, `\z`, and `\u` can match there. But not `\c`.

`\u`, of course, will only match if it can't match here:

> ```
> CharacterEscape ::
>   ControlEscape
>   c ControlLetter
>   HexEscapeSequence
>   UnicodeEscapeSequence
>   OctalEscapeSequence
>   IdentityEscape
> ```

Specifically:

> ```
> UnicodeEscapeSequence ::
>  u HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
> ```

But why `c`? Probably because it *is* special (and they might have forgotten they were covered under `c ControlLetter`). According to Regex101.com:

> `\cY` Matches ASCII characters typically associated with Control+A through Control+Z: \x01 through \x1A.

Regex101.com also explains how `\c` is parsed:

> `\c` matches the characters `\c` literally (case sensitive)

(I suspect that Firefox may treat `\u` similarly.)

---

...Unless you're using the `u` modifier. In that case, forget everything because `\u` and `\c` alone are errors.

In PCRE, (where `\u` and `\c` have the same meanings,) these regexes are errors with and without the `u` modifier. This behavior is "correct", at least in my mind.

---

**Bottom line: Unnecessary escapes are poorly defined and *should be errors*.

AVOID THEM.**

Comment: I'll accept the answer, but for the record, as far as I'm concerted the ECMAScript spec defines what's "correct" for a browser, not the behaviour of PCRE - and nor am I interested in what "should be" errors. The link to appendix B of the spec in ECMAScript 6 explains what the browsers are doing (ie it's a willful violation of ECMAScript 5, subsequently added as a permitted behaviour in ES6).